# an excursion in mathematics problem of Pythagoras theorem

Tags: geometry

In a right angled in which angle A is 90 a perpendicular is drawn to BC from A and it cuts BC at D . Show that AD.BC=CA.AB

Comment: What does the dot $.$ in AD.BC and CA.AB stand for?

Comment: Similar triangles. $ABD,CBA$ are similar, so $\frac{AB}{AD}=\frac{CB}{CA}$.

Comment: The dot means multiplication.

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b$ build the angle with $90°$, $c$ is the third side and $h$ the height over $c$, then the area of the triangle is

$$A=\frac{ab}{2}=\frac{hc}{2}$$